# Defining clickable region on image

Tags: c#, wpf, border, clickable

I want to make a Risk-like board game. The code and setup are no problem, however making the map and being able to define a country as clickable is.

I don't know where to start with this. Searching Google did not give me anything useful yet.

Any suggestions are welcome, however since this is a "just for fun" private project buying a component library is not somthing I want to do.

Comment: In WPF, any UI element can receive user input. So make e.g. a [`Path`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`Polygon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.polygon(v=vs.110).aspx) shape and handle the `MouseDown` event to detect clicks.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking in to it now. Looks prommising :)

Comment: Depending on the complexity of your board image, it may be possible to create a bitmap, then just check a pixel location and color on click. For example: `if (pixel.color == red) { //russia was clicked }`. Again, depends on your board and colors.

Comment: how do you represent a country , is it in item in an Items control ?

Comment: @eranotzap It is an image of a wordmap with regions defined on top of the map